# JQuery Password validation with length not reading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

below i have span weak, strong , very strong. i am trying to change the color of these spans depends of the length of the input value (password). i cant seem to figure out why my setup is working.i am i targeting it wrong? Another question is when i type the background color of other input should change from red to no color since i made if there is any value, remove red color, this is not working either:(

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var pa= $("#passid").val();
    var cp= $("#confirmpass").val();

    var x = $("#fnameid,#Lnameid,#emailid,#phoneid,#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year,#mf").val();
    
    
    if( x== null || x== "")
 {
  
        $("#fnameid,#Lnameid,#emailid,#phoneid,#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year,#mf").addClass("bordercoloron");
          return true;
  
    }
    
    else {
        
        $("#fnameid,#Lnameid,#emailid,#phoneid,#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year,#mf").removeClass("bordercoloron");
        
        return true;
    }
    
 
    if(pa.length<=5){

        $("#passstrength span").eq(0).css("color","red");
    }

    if(pa.length>5 && pa.length<=7 ){

        $("#passstrength span").eq(1).css("color","yellow");
    }

    if(pa.length>7 ){

        $("#passstrength span").eq(2).css("color","green");
    }


})

 function redirect(){
      
        window.location.href = "output.html";
        
    }
```

```css
#wraper{
margin: 0 auto;
height: 4000px;
width:1000px;
border: 2px solid black;

}
#wholeform{
 
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 700px;
 width: 400px;
 border: 2px solid grey;
}

#fnameid,#Lnameid{
 
 height: 50px;
 width: 172px;
 border:none;
 position: relative;
 left: 0.5%;
 margin-top:3%;
 padding-left: 5%;
 font-size: 20px;
 
}
#emailid,#phoneid{
 height: 50px;
 width: 372px;
 border:none;
 position: relative;
    left: 0.5%;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-left: 5%;
 letter-spacing: 9px;
 margin-top:5%;
 
}

#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year
{
 height: 50px;
 width: 120px;
 position: relative;
 left: 4%;
 border:none;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top:5%;
 color:darkgray
 
}
#mf{
 height: 55px;
 width: 350px;
 position: relative;
 left: 4%;
 border:none;
 font-size: 50px;
 margin-top:-2%;
 padding-left: 5%;
 letter-spacing: 10px;
 color:darkgray
 
 
 
}

.bordercoloron{
 
 background-color: coral;
}

.bordercoloroff{
 
 border: none;
}

#passid{
 height: 50px;
 width: 172px;
 border:none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 37.5%;
 margin-top:15%;
 padding-left: 1%;
 font-size: 20px;
 
}


#confirmid{
 
 height: 50px;
 width: 165px;
 border:none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50.5%;
 margin-top:15%;
 padding-left: 1%;
 font-size: 20px;
 
}

#passstrength{
 text-align: center;
 color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
 <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jexerinter.css">
</head>
 
<body>

   <div id="wrap">
 
 <div id="mainbox">
    
   <form  id="wholeform">
    <input type="text" placeholder="FirstName" name="fname" id="fnameid">
    <input type="text" placeholder="LastName" name="Lname" id="Lnameid"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email@example.com" name="email" id="emailid">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Phone Number" name="fname" id="phoneid">
    

     <select name="dob-day" id="dob-day"> 
       <option value="">Day</option> 
       <option value="">---</option> 
       <option value="01">01</option> 
       <option value="02">02</option> 
       <option value="03">03</option> 
       <option value="04">04</option> 
       <option value="05">05</option> 
       <option value="06">06</option> 
       <option value="07">07</option> 
       <option value="08">08</option> 
       <option value="09">09</option> 
       <option value="10">10</option> 
       <option value="11">11</option> 
       <option value="12">12</option> 
       <option value="13">13</option> 
       <option value="14">14</option> 
       <option value="15">15</option> 
       <option value="16">16</option> 
       <option value="17">17</option> 
       <option value="18">18</option> 
       <option value="19">19</option> 
       <option value="20">20</option> 
       <option value="21">21</option> 
       <option value="22">22</option> 
       <option value="23">23</option> 
       <option value="24">24</option> 
       <option value="25">25</option> 
       <option value="26">26</option> 
       <option value="27">27</option> 
       <option value="28">28</option> 
       <option value="29">29</option> 
       <option value="30">30</option> 
       <option value="31">31</option> 
     </select> 
     <select name="dob-month" id="dob-month"> 
       <option value="">Month</option> 
       <option value="">-----</option> 
       <option value="01">January</option> 
       <option value="02">February</option> 
       <option value="03">March</option> 
       <option value="04">April</option> 
       <option value="05">May</option> 
       <option value="06">June</option> 
       <option value="07">July</option> 
       <option value="08">August</option> 
       <option value="09">September</option> 
       <option value="10">October</option> 
       <option value="11">November</option> 
       <option value="12">December</option> 
     </select> 
     <select name="dob-year" id="dob-year"> 
       <option value="">Year</option> 
       <option value="">----</option> 
       <option value="2012">2012</option> 
       <option value="2011">2011</option> 
       <option value="2010">2010</option> 
       <option value="2009">2009</option> 
       <option value="2008">2008</option> 
       <option value="2007">2007</option> 
       <option value="2006">2006</option> 
       <option value="2005">2005</option> 
       <option value="2004">2004</option> 
       <option value="2003">2003</option> 
       <option value="2002">2002</option> 
       <option value="2001">2001</option> 
       <option value="2000">2000</option> 
       <option value="1999">1999</option> 
       <option value="1998">1998</option> 
       <option value="1997">1997</option> 
       <option value="1996">1996</option> 
       <option value="1995">1995</option> 
       <option value="1994">1994</option> 
       <option value="1993">1993</option> 
       <option value="1992">1992</option> 
       <option value="1991">1991</option> 
       
     </select> 
   
    <h3 style="font-size:20px; position: relative; left:5%; width:70px;color:darkgray;">Gender:</h3>   
    <select id="mf">
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
    </select>
    
    
   
   <input type="button" id="submit" style="background-color:#2196F3;border-radius:5px;border:2px #2196F3;position:relative; margin-top:25%;left:25%;width:200px;height:80px;font-size:50px;color:darkgray; padding-left:5%;" value="SignUp" onclick="redirect()">
    
    
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="Pass" id="passid" >
    
    <input type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmpass" id="confirmid">
    
  <p id="passstrength"><span>Weak  </span> <span>Strong  </span><span>Very strong</span></p>
   </form>   
   
 
    
    
 </div>
 

 
 </div>
 
 
<script src="../js/jexercise.js"></script>    
   
</body>
 
 
 
</html>
```

Comment: `pa` is value typed in password, in `if(pa.val().length<=5) {` remove `.val()`.

Comment: tho that was a typo, even after removing, still not changing the span color tho :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix following in your code,

```
if(pa.val().length<=5){
    $("#passstrength span").eq(0).css("color","red");
}
```

"pa" is already a value

```
var pa= $("#passid").val();
```

It should be,

```
 if(pa.length<=5){
    $("#passstrength span").eq(0).css("color","red");
 }
```

EDIT 2 : You need to fix your flow instead. You are returning even before the flow comes to validation and changing color. Also you need to do onchange event on your password field where it will on change color based on length as follows, in you current code it is done on ready() which is not correct incremently / dynamic validations.

Do like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#passid").change(function(){

    var pa= $(this).val();
    var cp= $("#confirmpass").val();

    if(pa.length<=5){
       
      $("span#weak").css("color","red");
    }

    if(pa.length>5 && pa.length<=7 ){
       $("span#strong").css("color","yellow");
    }

    if(pa.length>7 ){
      $("span#vstrong").css("color","green");
    }

});

    var x = $("#fnameid,#Lnameid,#emailid,#phoneid,#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year,#mf").val();

    if( x== null || x== "")
    {
       $("#fnameid,#Lnameid,#emailid,#phoneid,#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year,#mf").addClass("bordercoloron");
      
    }

    else {

       $("#fnameid,#Lnameid,#emailid,#phoneid,#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year,#mf").removeClass("bordercoloron");

      return true;
    }
  });

 function redirect(){
     window.location.href = "output.html";
 }
```

```css
#wraper{
margin: 0 auto;
height: 4000px;
width:1000px;
border: 2px solid black;

}
#wholeform{
 
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 700px;
 width: 400px;
 border: 2px solid grey;
}

#fnameid,#Lnameid{
 
 height: 50px;
 width: 172px;
 border:none;
 position: relative;
 left: 0.5%;
 margin-top:3%;
 padding-left: 5%;
 font-size: 20px;
 
}
#emailid,#phoneid{
 height: 50px;
 width: 372px;
 border:none;
 position: relative;
    left: 0.5%;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-left: 5%;
 letter-spacing: 9px;
 margin-top:5%;
 
}

#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year
{
 height: 50px;
 width: 120px;
 position: relative;
 left: 4%;
 border:none;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top:5%;
 color:darkgray
 
}
#mf{
 height: 55px;
 width: 350px;
 position: relative;
 left: 4%;
 border:none;
 font-size: 50px;
 margin-top:-2%;
 padding-left: 5%;
 letter-spacing: 10px;
 color:darkgray
 
 
 
}

.bordercoloron{
 
 background-color: coral;
}

.bordercoloroff{
 
 border: none;
}

#passid{
 height: 50px;
 width: 172px;
 border:none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 37.5%;
 margin-top:15%;
 padding-left: 1%;
 font-size: 20px;
 
}


#confirmid{
 
 height: 50px;
 width: 165px;
 border:none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50.5%;
 margin-top:15%;
 padding-left: 1%;
 font-size: 20px;
 
}

#passstrength{
 text-align: center;
 color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
 
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
 <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jexerinter.css">
</head>
 
<body>

   <div id="wrap">
 
 <div id="mainbox">
    
   <form  id="wholeform">
    <input type="text" placeholder="FirstName" name="fname" id="fnameid">
    <input type="text" placeholder="LastName" name="Lname" id="Lnameid"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email@example.com" name="email" id="emailid">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Phone Number" name="fname" id="phoneid">
    

     <select name="dob-day" id="dob-day"> 
       <option value="">Day</option> 
       <option value="">---</option> 
       <option value="01">01</option> 
       <option value="02">02</option> 
       <option value="03">03</option> 
       <option value="04">04</option> 
       <option value="05">05</option> 
       <option value="06">06</option> 
       <option value="07">07</option> 
       <option value="08">08</option> 
       <option value="09">09</option> 
       <option value="10">10</option> 
       <option value="11">11</option> 
       <option value="12">12</option> 
       <option value="13">13</option> 
       <option value="14">14</option> 
       <option value="15">15</option> 
       <option value="16">16</option> 
       <option value="17">17</option> 
       <option value="18">18</option> 
       <option value="19">19</option> 
       <option value="20">20</option> 
       <option value="21">21</option> 
       <option value="22">22</option> 
       <option value="23">23</option> 
       <option value="24">24</option> 
       <option value="25">25</option> 
       <option value="26">26</option> 
       <option value="27">27</option> 
       <option value="28">28</option> 
       <option value="29">29</option> 
       <option value="30">30</option> 
       <option value="31">31</option> 
     </select> 
     <select name="dob-month" id="dob-month"> 
       <option value="">Month</option> 
       <option value="">-----</option> 
       <option value="01">January</option> 
       <option value="02">February</option> 
       <option value="03">March</option> 
       <option value="04">April</option> 
       <option value="05">May</option> 
       <option value="06">June</option> 
       <option value="07">July</option> 
       <option value="08">August</option> 
       <option value="09">September</option> 
       <option value="10">October</option> 
       <option value="11">November</option> 
       <option value="12">December</option> 
     </select> 
     <select name="dob-year" id="dob-year"> 
       <option value="">Year</option> 
       <option value="">----</option> 
       <option value="2012">2012</option> 
       <option value="2011">2011</option> 
       <option value="2010">2010</option> 
       <option value="2009">2009</option> 
       <option value="2008">2008</option> 
       <option value="2007">2007</option> 
       <option value="2006">2006</option> 
       <option value="2005">2005</option> 
       <option value="2004">2004</option> 
       <option value="2003">2003</option> 
       <option value="2002">2002</option> 
       <option value="2001">2001</option> 
       <option value="2000">2000</option> 
       <option value="1999">1999</option> 
       <option value="1998">1998</option> 
       <option value="1997">1997</option> 
       <option value="1996">1996</option> 
       <option value="1995">1995</option> 
       <option value="1994">1994</option> 
       <option value="1993">1993</option> 
       <option value="1992">1992</option> 
       <option value="1991">1991</option> 
       
     </select> 
   
    <h3 style="font-size:20px; position: relative; left:5%; width:70px;color:darkgray;">Gender:</h3>   
    <select id="mf">
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
    </select>
    
    
   
   <input type="button" id="submit" style="background-color:#2196F3;border-radius:5px;border:2px #2196F3;position:relative; margin-top:25%;left:25%;width:200px;height:80px;font-size:50px;color:darkgray; padding-left:5%;" value="SignUp" onclick="redirect()">
    
    
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="Pass" id="passid" /><br/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmpass" id="confirmid" /> <br/>   
  <span id="weak">Weak</span> 
        <span id="strong">Strong  </span>
        <span id="vstrong">Very strong</span>
   </form>     
    
 </div>
 </div>   
   
</body>
 
 
 
</html>
```

Fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/9cGxs/

Comment: sorry that was actually a typo, as you can see , i didn't use pa.val for the rest of if else . its still not changing color after the removal of pa.val

Comment: i have done exactly this and also gave each span and id (if(pa.length<=5){
      $("#weak").css("color","red");) but some reason its still not changing color. i am using bracket and also tried with sublime. i was editing in fiddle and the weak span turned red. nothing else changed. Any clue?

Comment: @AnuRajan i have updated my answer. You need to add change event on your password input field.

Comment: hey still seem to not change . i have updated with latest fix by using your suggestion. please review

Comment: @AnuRajan i can not review due to lack of reputations. But need clarification that you would need to remove css which are already applied so that your new validation color is only seen

Comment: well, that was for the first name, last name, email etc. but password i want to change the color of the span weak, strong ,very strong according to the if else definition

Comment: @AnuRajan I have added a fiddle link check that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128234/discussion-between-techbreak-and-anu-rajan).

Comment: @AnuRajan please check the working snippet. I have added entire working code in answer. Please accept if it works for you as well.

Comment: thankyou it worked when u add change. But for some reason it wasn't changing the color. But on fiddle, when i click update every time i enter a number of value the color change. let me know why its not changing the color right away without me clicking update. other than that you answer is perfect

Answer (score 0):

This is because your if/else condition executes before your length check

```
if( x== null || x== "")
{

    $("#fnameid,#Lnameid,#emailid,#phoneid,#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year,#mf").addClass("bordercoloron");
      return true;

}

else {

    $("#fnameid,#Lnameid,#emailid,#phoneid,#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year,#mf").removeClass("bordercoloron");

    return true;
}
```

Either remove this else condition OR execute your length check code before

Comment: i moved length to the top like the user "TechBreak" displayed. still not changing the background color. is return necessary ?

Comment: @AnuRajan i have updated my answer. You need to add change event on your password input field.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the return statement from your 'if' clause.

Otherwise, your code will return before executing the rest of the code:

```
if( x== null || x== "")
{   
    $("#fnameid,#Lnameid,#emailid,#phoneid,#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year,#mf").addClass("bordercoloron");   
}

else {      
    $("#fnameid,#Lnameid,#emailid,#phoneid,#dob-day,#dob-month,#dob-year,#mf").removeClass("bordercoloron");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

change `if(pa.val().length<=5)` to `if(pa.length<=5)`

**Edit**

```
$("#passid").bind('input', function() { 
     var pa=  $(this).val();
      if(pa.length<=5){
         $("#passstrength").html("<span style='color:red'>Weak</span>");
      }
      else if(pa.length>5 && pa.length<=7 ){
         $("#passstrength").html("<span style='color:yellow'>Strong</span>");
      }else{
         $("#passstrength").html("<span style='color:green'>Very Strong</span>");
      }
});
```

Comment: sorry that was actually a typo, as you can see , i didn't use pa.val for the rest of if else. fixing that still not changing color??

Comment: A simple fix would be to put id selectors on the spans. So `<span id="weak">Weak  </span> <span id="strong">Strong  </span><span id="veryStrong">Very strong</span>` then calling that directly  $("#weak").css("color","red");

Comment: this seems to fix by changing the color of weak to red, but when .length = more than 5 strong and very strong is not responding

Comment: Try the edited version and remove the span elements from the html

Comment: @jwpfox can you explain how that this doesn't provide an answer? also the orgional question if you look in the logs had the error of pa.val()